# How to add/subtract n number of days from a custom date in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a database in which, I have a issue_date column, and forecast_date column,

[image: database]

I am selecting the maximum date from the database,

but I want to fetch/query/extract the N th previous day from maximum available date

like (maximum date - 1 / 2 or n number of days).

```
SELECT issue_date, forecast_date, state_name, district_name, rainfall, geometry 
FROM all_parameters_forecast_data 
WHERE "forecast_date" = (SELECT ((MAX("forecast_date")- INTERVAL '1 day') AS "forecast_date") FROM all_parameters_forecast_data)
```

& As the max date is custom,

so can not use today or yesterday logic here.
Is there any way possible?

Comment: I've removed the product tags you apparently don't use. Please *only* tag products involved in the question

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: thanks @BritishSteel, the datatype of columns was test, I changed the datatype of column to date and the code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calculate the MAX date
2. Filter your records using `BETWEEN max_date - n AND max_date`

Example:

```
SELECT issue_date, forecast_date, state_name, district_name, rainfall, geometry 
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        MAX("forecast_data") OVER () as max_forecast_date
    FROM 
        all_parameters_forecast_data
) s
WHERE "forecast_date" BETWEEN max_forecast_date - n AND max_forecast_date
```

There are many ways to achieve **#1**. In my example I used the `MAX()` window function to add the required value as separate column which can be used for comparison later.